# How can I delete rows/items of pandas series with indices' labels not in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, series

I have a list of labels.

I also have a pandas series that has multiple rows/items, some of which have their index labels in that list and some others have index labels not in that list.

I want to delete the rows/items of that series that have labels not in that list.

The only way I could come up with is to iterate on the series, check if the index label is in that list or not and delete it if not.

Is there any other easier way? And if not, could someone provide a code to do this way, as I also couldn't get it to work (not sure how to iterate on a series and how to compare its index labels to labels in a list).

Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you think select columns by list like `df[labels]` ? Or by index values like `df.loc[labels]` ?

Comment: won't `df = df.drop(list_with_labels_missing)` work?

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant raw data, your code, attempts and desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,5,6], index=list('abcd'))
print (s)
a    1
b    2
c    5
d    6
dtype: int64

L = list('cdef')
print (s.loc[s.index.intersection(L)])
c    5
d    6
dtype: int64
```

Another posible solution with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (s.loc[s.index.isin(L)])
c    5
d    6
dtype: int64
```